# VirtualBox resume from hibernate does not mount shared folder

Tags: virtualbox, hibernate, shared-folders

I am facing the problem that after returning from hibernate, it does not mount the shared folder anymore.

As the following shows in /media folder:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    6 May  2  2014 cdrom -> cdrom0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May  2  2014 cdrom0
d????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? sf_Dropbox
d????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? sf_Google_Drive
```

Therefore the ln -s in home folder returns unable to access it.

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 ethanlim ethanlim 4096 May  2  2014 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x 3 ethanlim ethanlim 4096 Nov  9 16:31 Documents
drwxr-xr-x 2 ethanlim ethanlim 4096 Nov 10 01:15 Downloads
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root     root       17 Aug 15 20:35 Dropbox -> /media/sf_Dropbox
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root     root       22 Aug 23 00:15 GoogleDrive -> /media/sf_Google_Drive
drwxr-xr-x 2 ethanlim ethanlim 4096 May  2  2014 Music
drwxr-xr-x 2 ethanlim ethanlim 4096 May  2  2014 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x 2 ethanlim ethanlim 4096 May  2  2014 Public
drwxr-xr-x 5 ethanlim ethanlim 4096 Aug 22 22:59 Settings
drwxr-xr-x 2 ethanlim ethanlim 4096 May  2  2014 Templates
drwxr-xr-x 2 ethanlim ethanlim 4096 May  2  2014 Videos
```

Does anyone face this issue?

Comment: Could it be related to this? https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14374